# Does Django create useless migrations?

Tags: django, django-models

When I change the `verbose_name` attribute of a Django Model, Django will generate a related migration (running `make migrations` command).

However, without applying the migration (`migrate` command), the change seems to be applied all over the Django project. I think this is because `verbose_name` is something used at Django level rather than at database level.

This makes me wonder: what is the purpose of this migration file?

Comment: Django indeed sometimes creates "useless" migrations. That is because certain _backends_ might do something at the database level (like altering the comment, or defining choices), whereas most backends will perhaps not do anything.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks, that makes sense. I'll try to see if there is way to configure Django to NOT create these migration files though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django makes abstraction of the backend used. Indeed, you can use a different backend, by altering the `settings.py` file. In fact you can define a backend yourself.

All changes to the models thus *can* have impact on the database. You could for example define a backend that uses the `verbose_name` of a column as the "comment string" you frequently can add to such column at the database side. If you for example define `choices`, then a backend could, for some databases, try to enforce these choices at database level.

Since, as said before, Django aims to work unaware of the backend used, it thus aims to be conservative, and make migrations for a lot of model changes. For some of these, the backend will decide to simply do *nothing*. So no query is constructed, and nothing is changed at the database side. You can indeed see such changes as "useless migrations". But keep in mind that if you later would use a different backend, these "useless migrations" might in fact do something.

Since such migrations do not do anything on the database side, these are however usually not time cosuming. You might want to look to ["*squash*" migration files [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#migration-squashing) together, and thus reduce the number of migration files used. The migrations will still be part of the file, but since there are no queries involved, it will usually not do much harm.

Furthermore, you can in fact patch the `deconstruct` function on a field, such that the `help_text`, etc. do not appear in the result of a `deconstruct` call anymore and thus are not visible to the "detector". This [Gist script](https://gist.github.com/vdboor/e3754e19551f2fbbcc31b01eec99ee8e) shows a way to patch the `makemigration` command:

> ```
> """
> Patch the creation of database migrations in Django
> Import this early from `__init__.py``.
> - Don't want verbose_name changes in the migrations file.
> - Don't want help_text in the migrations file.
> """
> from functools import wraps
>
> from django.db.models import Field
>
>
> def patch_deconstruct(old_func, condition):
>     """
>     Patch the ``Field.deconstruct`` to remove useless information.
>     This only happens on internal apps, not third party apps.
>     """
>
>     @wraps(old_func)
>     def new_deconstruct(self):
>         name, path, args, kwargs = old_func(self)
>         # AutoField has no model on creation, but can be skipped
>         if hasattr(self, 'model') and condition(self):
>             kwargs.pop('verbose_name', None)
>             kwargs.pop('help_text', None)
>         return name, path, args, kwargs
>     return new_deconstruct
>
>
> Field.deconstruct = patch_deconstruct(Field.deconstruct, lambda self: self.model.__module__.startswith('apps.'))
> ```

Comment: Is it possible to hint Django which attributes of fields do not affect my current backend and thus it shouldn't create migration if these field attributes change? Something like `exclude_attributes = ('choices', 'verbose_name')`

Comment: @radoh: you can "monkey patch" the `destruct`: https://gist.github.com/vdboor/e3754e19551f2fbbcc31b01eec99ee8e I think one could make a package to do this with a setting, like you describe. So technically speaking it is possible.